# Why there is no concept of deny in security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

What's is the reason that makes security groups unable to deny some sort of traffic whereas it's possible with NACLs?

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume mainly for performance reasons. All rules are validated and applied on the network interface level which dependent on total hosts on the physical host. By implicitely denying unless a rules there it reduces the computational requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "reason" other than "because that's how it was designed."

Security groups deny everything by default, and traffic matching any rule allows that traffic to pass, so there is no need for rule precedence as there would be for a mix of allow/deny.  This in turn is means a simpler interface and likely a simpler and more lightweight implementation, though the actual reason may not be related to that but may simply be that NACL already provides this feature.